# Why would an if statement insist on printing a value?

Tags: templating, plugin-sproutforms

I'm confused over this simple problem of a conditional printing "1" instead of behaving normally, and I can't figure out why it's happening.

### Goal

```
<p>
    <label for="contactFirstName" class="required">First Name*</label>
    <input name="contactFirstName" value="" class="required">
</p>
```

### Attempt

I've passed a `field` variable that contains the following (among other things)...

- `handle` (string) => `"contactFirstName"`
- `label` (string) => `"First Name"`
- `required` (boolean) => `true`

...into a macro...

```
{% macro labeledInput(field) %}
    <p>
        <label for="{{ field.handle }}"{% if field.required %} class="required"{% endif %}>
            {{ field.label }}{% if field.required %}*{% endif %}
        </label>
        <input name="{{ field.handle }}" value=""{% if field.required %} class="required"{% endif %}>
    </p>
{% endmacro %}
```

### Result/Mystery

"Couldn't be easier!", we're all thinking. Except that the markup comes out like this:

```
<p>
    <label for="contactFirstName"1>
        First Name1     
    </label>
    <input name="contactFirstName" value=""1>
</p>
```

**Potential Clues**

- If I add `{% if true == true %}foo{% endif %}` in the macro, I'll get `foo` and not a `1`.
- When the value of `required` is `false`, nothing prints (as you'd expect).
- It doesn't seem to matter whether I'm using a macro, an include, or whether I try the same thing in my parent template.
- The `field` object is a Sprout Forms `SproutForms_HtmlDisplay`, if that ends up being significant.

**How is it possible for `{% if field.required %}*{% endif %}` to print a `1`?**

---

**{{ dump(field) }}**:

```
object(Craft\SproutForms_HtmlDisplay)#544 (1) {
  ["htmlFields":"Craft\SproutForms_HtmlDisplay":private] => array(10) {
    ["input"] => string(145) "
        <input class="text nicetext fullwidth" type="text" id="contactFirstName" name="contactFirstName" value="" autocomplete="off" placeholder="">
    "
    ["handle"] => string(16) "contactFirstName"
    ["type"] => string(9) "plaintext"
    ["settings"] =>
      array(4) {
        ["placeholder"] => string(0) ""
        ["maxLength"] => string(0) ""
        ["multiline"] => string(0) ""
        ["initialRows"] => string(1) "4"
      }
    ["validation"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0] => string(8) "required"
      }
    ["required"] => bool(true)
    ["instructions"] => string(0) ""
    ["hint"] => string(0) ""
    ["label"] => string(10) "First Name"
    ["error"] => string(0) ""
  }
}
```

---

**compiled template for macro**:

```
/* macros/forms */
class __TwigTemplate_6b53fb724811bc086c93653f7ad8519f9f9b0f194a80bfde00a078376bde6a36 extends Craft\BaseTemplate
{
    public function __construct(Twig_Environment $env)
    {
        parent::__construct($env);

        $this->parent = false;

        $this->blocks = array(
        );
    }

    protected function doDisplay(array $context, array $blocks = array())
    {
    }

    // line 1
    public function getlabeledInput($_field = null)
    {
        $context = $this->env->mergeGlobals(array(
            "field" => $_field,
        ));

        $blocks = array();

        ob_start();
        try {
            // line 2
            echo "
\t<p>
\t\t<label for=\"";
            // line 4
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $this->getAttribute((isset($context["field"]) ? $context["field"] : $this->getContext($context, "field")), "handle"), "html", null, true);
            echo "\"";
            if ((!twig_test_empty($this->getAttribute((isset($context["field"]) ? $context["field"] : $this->getContext($context, "field")), "required")))) {
                echo " class=\"required\"";
            }
            echo ">
\t\t\t";
            // line 5
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $this->getAttribute((isset($context["field"]) ? $context["field"] : $this->getContext($context, "field")), "label"), "html", null, true);
            if ((!twig_test_empty($this->getAttribute((isset($context["field"]) ? $context["field"] : $this->getContext($context, "field")), "required")))) {
                echo "*";
            }
            // line 6
            echo "\t\t</label>
\t\t<input name=\"";
            // line 7
            echo twig_escape_filter($this->env, $this->getAttribute((isset($context["field"]) ? $context["field"] : $this->getContext($context, "field")), "handle"), "html", null, true);
            echo "\" value=\"\"";
            if ((!twig_test_empty($this->getAttribute((isset($context["field"]) ? $context["field"] : $this->getContext($context, "field")), "required")))) {
                echo " class=\"required\"";
            }
            echo ">
\t</p>

";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            ob_end_clean();

            throw $e;
        }

        return ('' === $tmp = ob_get_clean()) ? '' : new Twig_Markup($tmp, $this->env->getCharset());
    }

    public function getTemplateName()
    {
        return "macros/forms";
    }

    public function isTraitable()
    {
        return false;
    }

    public function getDebugInfo()
    {
        return array (  36 => 4,  169 => 122,  163 => 114,  155 => 112,  147 => 110,  143 => 109,  139 => 108,  131 => 106,  127 => 105,  124 => 104,  122 => 103,  119 => 102,  117 => 101,  46 => 28,  40 => 26,  33 => 22,  21 => 1,  54 => 21,  44 => 5,  38 => 25,  32 => 2,  26 => 7,  19 => 1,  347 => 180,  330 => 168,  318 => 159,  314 => 158,  303 => 150,  299 => 149,  295 => 148,  266 => 126,  263 => 125,  260 => 124,  255 => 121,  238 => 107,  232 => 106,  224 => 103,  216 => 100,  191 => 80,  187 => 78,  176 => 75,  171 => 74,  167 => 73,  159 => 113,  135 => 107,  110 => 22,  87 => 182,  85 => 180,  82 => 29,  80 => 124,  77 => 123,  75 => 26,  72 => 25,  70 => 21,  65 => 19,  56 => 22,  49 => 6,  42 => 14,  34 => 6,  29 => 8,  25 => 2,  23 => 1,  151 => 111,  148 => 94,  146 => 93,  123 => 73,  115 => 68,  107 => 21,  98 => 57,  94 => 56,  81 => 45,  79 => 28,  61 => 23,  52 => 7,  50 => 19,  31 => 4,  28 => 3,);
    }
}
```

---

**Point of Failure !**

I'm not even sure what this means, but this automatically-generated conditional from the compiled template...

```
if ($this->getAttribute((isset($context["field"]) ? $context["field"] : $this->getContext($context, "field")), "required")) {
    echo "pony";
}
```

...produces a `1`. If I cheat...

```
if ($context["field"]->required) {
     echo "pony";
}
```

...I get `pony` instead.

---

**Hacking at SproutFormsVariable.php**

If I make `_getFieldOutput()` return a dumb array instead of an instance of `SproutForms_HtmlDisplay`, the template will parse properly...

```
$field['handle']   = $handle;
$field['label']    = $fieldInfo->name;
$field['required'] = in_array('required', $fieldModel->validation) ? true : false;

return $field;
```

Comment: Odd... what happens if you do {% if field.required == true %}?

Comment: @BradBell The exact same thing. Ditto `is empty`.

Comment: Can you {{ dump(field) }} and see what it outputs?

Comment: @BradBell Added. That "required" value is always present, and correctly `true` or `false`.

Comment: Hrm... try clearing out your craft/storage/runtime/compiled_templates folder, reproduce the problem, look into that folder and find the compiled template that contains your macro, and post the PHP / compiled Twig code for your macro.

Comment: I'm stumped. If you're familiar with xDebug at all, you can throw a breakpoint on: "if ((!twig_test_empty($this->getAttribute((isset($context["field"]) ? $context["field"] : $this->getContext($context, "field")), "required")))) {" and step into it to see what's going on.

Comment: @BradBell I'll get the xDebug microscope on it now that I know where to look. Thanks for helping and confirming I'm not crazy (this time)!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15764/discussion-between-brad-bell-and-matt-stein).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow Matt, awful question! You should probably have a moderator remove it so nobody else has to suffer.

In `SproutForms_HtmlDisplay`, change the `__call()` function's `echo`...

```
public function __call($key, $args)
{
    if (isset($this->htmlFields[$key]))
    {
        echo $this->htmlFields[$key];
    }
}
```

...to a `return`...

```
public function __call($key, $args)
{
    if (isset($this->htmlFields[$key]))
    {
        return $this->htmlFields[$key];
    }
}
```

Comment: We will be sure to remove this and change everything here on you in the next version of the plugin =)

Comment: @Ben Once I finally accept and remove this Q&A, nobody will even know it happened anyway!

Comment: The odd thing is, I think this got introduced recently.  But the next version of the plugin is on the horizon (and that file will no longer exist), so I haven't dug in to try to figure out why.

Comment: @Ben I extroduced it from this build, and now all's well! Happy to take one hopelessly trivial item off your list :)